# Selection Box, deselect other options if select ALL is picked

Tags: jquery

I have a selection box like below:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="1">
    <option value="-1">ALL</option>
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
    <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

now as per the requirement if user select option `ALL` then rest of the values (if selected) gets automatic deselected.
For ex- if I select option2 and option 3 and then If I select ALL then option2 and option3 should be deselected

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted to write yourself to solve this problem.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ufuzC/1/

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ufuzC/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think second fiddle which you have given is a answer. why don't you put this as an answer for this question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That was my first post so will post the attempted solutions too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $select = $('select[name="1"]'),
        $all = $select.find('option[value="-1"]'),
        $opts = $select.find('option').not($all)
        $select.change(function () {
            if ($all.is(':selected')) {
                $opts.prop('selected', false);
            } else {
                $all.prop('selected', false);
            }
        });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ufuzC/)

Comment: by using `disabled`, the user cant change the selection again.